# how to change file content-Type into multipart / form data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, multipartform-data, multipart, antd

i have this kind of file data

```
{uid: "vc-upload-1577940007821-10", lastModified: 1552282096988, lastModifiedDate: Mon Mar 11 2019 13:28:16 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time), name: "Backup Call.pdf", size: 30973, …}
```

that is received from ant design vue upload. i'm clueless how is multipart / form data is look like. i need to send this as a request into a post API. but the API is requires me to send in multipart form. how can i change this data into multipart form?
is there any referenced, function or any way i could change this data into multipart format?

this is what my structure look like:

```
<a-upload-dragger
  name="File"
  :multiple="true"
  action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
  @change="handleChange"
  :beforeUpload="checkFormat"
  :showUploadList="false"
></a-upload-dragger>
```

and this is the function i used:

```
checkFormat(file) {
  const isPDF = file.type === 'application/pdf';
  if (!isPDF) {
    this.$message.error('You can only upload PDF file!');
  }
  return isPDF;
},
handleChange(info) {
  if (info.file.status === 'done') {
    this.uploadFile(info.file);
    this.$message.success(`${info.file.name} file upload successfully.`);
  } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
    this.$message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
  }
},
```

i want to create a function that change the format into multipart in `theuploadFile()` function

Comment: The purpose is not to change the data into "multipart", rather it's the content type of the form/AJAX request you're posting. See [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

Comment: @Teemu, i have tried to change the type of the file into multipart but nothing is happen. it just change the type. but still not work to post it. is the file type and content-type is different? how can i can change the content-type?

Comment: No, it's not type of file, it's __type of form__. I don't know Vue, but ex. in a HTML form you change the type with `enc` attribute. Please follow the link I've provided in my previous comment.